# Can Jquery take the form input straight from the form, or do I have to use a SET button in my script?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a script that is a simple countdown. 
You can put in a number press SET and then click START and the number will count down.

I use this in the gym, but I forget to press the SET button a lot after entering the new count.

Is it possible to let jquery take the form input or do I have to use a SET button?

```
var CCOUNT;
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#btnct').click(function() {
    CCOUNT = $('#seconds').val();
    cdreset();
  });
});
var t, count;

function cddisplay() {
  document.getElementById('timespan').innerHTML = count;

}

function countdown() {
  // starts countdown
  cddisplay();
  changeColor(CCOUNT);
  if (count === 0) {
    // time is up

  } else {
    count--;
    t = setTimeout(countdown, 1000);
    $("#onebuttons").attr('disabled', 'disabled');

  }
}

function cdpause() {
  // pauses countdown
  clearTimeout(t);
  $("#onebuttons").removeAttr('disabled');
}

function cdreset() {
  // resets countdown
  cdpause();
  count = CCOUNT;
  cddisplay();
  $("#onebuttons").removeAttr('disabled');
}

function changeColor() {
  if (count <= 1000 && count > 29) {
    document.getElementById('timespan').style.color = "#00CC00";

  } else if (count <= 29 && count > 9) {
    document.getElementById('timespan').style.color = "#F87217";
  } else if (count <= 9 && count > 3) {
    document.getElementById('timespan').style.color = "#ff0000";
  } else if (count === 3) {

    var audio = document.createElement("audio");
    audio.src = "3-2-1-0.m4a";
    audio.play();
  }

  if (count === 0) {
    document.getElementById('timespan').style.color = "#ffffff";

  }
  if (count < 10) {
    $("#timespan").fadeOut('slow', function() {
      $("#timespan").text(count);
      $("#timespan").fadeIn();
    });

  }
}
```

Comment: Hm.. if you don't use SET button, then how do you know when to start?

Comment: I'd like to fill in the form, then press the start button. Now I have to fill in the form, press set, press start.

Answer (score 0):

yes, just let the call out of the on click method 
like this

```
var CCOUNT;
$(document).ready(function() {
    CCOUNT = $('#seconds').val();
    cdreset();
});
```

It will make your method fire at the time the page finnish loads